# Quasar Q-Table and Data from Array (IndexedDB & Dexie)

Tags: qtableview, quasar-framework

I am new to Quasar and Javascript and I'm trying to get data from my database (IndexedDB using Dexie) into my q-table.

I have the skeleton of the q-table and I'm getting the data from Dexie, in the form of an Array, but I don't know how to display the data in the table and I would love some help.

I've read about maybe having to use computed, and/or the map option but I don't know enough about either of those to use them.  I've been googling and reading the Quasar docs and I'm still not sure what to do. I don't know if I can put it in a codepen since it's getting data from a database.

I have this live online at https://entrypaws.com/  you may have to hit shift-reload to get the latest version as my host has an online cache it keeps, though I've cleared it. This small table section is reachable by clicking the 'view test table' link in the left sidebar.

Here is my html:

```
<q-page>

wholething: {{ this.thePersonArray }} // this displays correc
<br/><br/>
hmmm: {{ this.thePersonArray[0].f_lastName }}

<q-table
      title="Treats"
      :rows="rows"
      :columns="columns"
      row-key="name"
      binary-state-sort
    >
      <template v-slot:body="props">
        <q-tr :props="props">

          <q-td key="name" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.name }}
          </q-td>

          <q-td key="lname" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.lname }}
          </q-td>

          <q-td key="dogbreed" :props="props">
            <div class="text-pre-wrap">{{ props.row.dogbreed }}</div>
          </q-td>

          <q-td key="phone" :props="props">
            {{ props.row.phone }}
          </q-td>
          
        </q-tr>
      </template>
    </q-table>

</q-page>
</template>
```

and this is my script:

````
import { ref } from "vue"
import theDB from "../components/dexiedb.js"

const columns = [
    {
        name: 'name',
        label: 'First Name',
        field: row => row.name,   // f_lastname:           
    },
    { name: 'lname', label: 'Last Name', field: 'lname'}, 
    { name: 'dogbreed', label: 'Dog Breed', field: 'dogbreed'},
    { name: 'phone', label: 'Phone', field: 'phone'},
]
const rows = [
    {
    name: 'Susan', 
    lname: 'Smith',
    dogbreed: 'Danish-Swedish Farmdog',
    phone: '801.810.9990',
    },
    {
    name: 'James',
    lname: 'Jones',
    dogbreed: 'Kromfohrlander',
    phone: '801.930.9999',
    },
]

export default {
  name: "testtable",
  setup() {
    return {
        columns,
        rows
        }
    }, // end setup

  data() {
    return {
      thePersonArray: [],
    }
  }, // end data

  created() {
    this.getTheUsers()
  }, // end mounted

    
  methods: {

    getTheUsers() {
      this.thePersonArray = []
      console.log(" getTheUsers 1 ", this.thePersonArray)
      
      this.thePersonArray.push({f_lastName: "Dreamer"}) // if the array is not initialized i seem toget an error

      theDB.personTable
      .orderBy('f_lastName')
      .each((personOBJ) => {
        this.thePersonArray.push(personOBJ)
        console.log(" inside: ", this.thePersonArray)
      }).then(() => {
          // Transaction committed. 
          console.log("     People: Transaction committed")
      }).catch(err => {
          // Transaction aborted. 
          console.log("     People: Transaction aborted")
      })
      console.log(" after done: ", this.thePersonArray)
    }

  }, // end methods
} // end export
</script>```

I'd love some help. I'm completely stuck.  


  [1]: https://entrypaws.com/
````

Answer (score 0):

Try making `thePersonArray` reactive by using `ref`

```
data() {
    return {
      thePersonArray: ref([]),
    }
},
```

then assign the new array to `thePersonArray.value`

```
    getTheUsers() {
      this.thePersonArray.value = []
```

I think you might be able to push directly with thePersonArray as I think Vue maps/ wraps/ proxies these methods (whatever they call it :) ), so try
`this.thePersonArray.push({f_lastName: "Dreamer"})`

and if that doesnt work try
`this.thePersonArray.value.push({f_lastName: "Dreamer"})`

but I think the first will work

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm still working on this off and on and still haven't been able to get it to work. I am thinking I need to load my data into the columns or rows but it's not working.  Like maybe field: row => row.name, having to be field: row => this. thePersonArray.f_name but that's not working either.